# Java while loop sentinel issue

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, sentinel

My while loop runs fine and the sentinel (String End) value ends the loop...the issue is that the when the sentinel is entered, the else println statement occurs.

I want the sentinel value to end the loop and not have the final else statement occur

```
while (!nameSearch.equalsIgnoreCase(sentinel)) {

      showMenu();
      nameSearch = keyboard.nextLine();

      if (girlList.contains(nameSearch.toLowerCase()) && 
         boyList.contains(nameSearch.toLowerCase())) {
         System.out.println("Name found in both boy and girl names\n");
       } else if (boyList.contains(nameSearch.toLowerCase())) {
            System.out.println("Boy name found");
       } else if (girlList.contains(nameSearch.toLowerCase())) {
             System.out.println("Girl name found");
       } else {
             System.out.println("Name not found");
       }
}

System.out.println("program end");
```

Comment: Swap the order of operations, assign at the end of the loop.

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve what you want.  One method would be to check if the sentinel value was entered, and break out of the loop immediately if it was:

```
if ((nameSearch = keyboard.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase(sentinel)) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just break the loop once value equal to sentinel value

```
showMenu();
      nameSearch = keyboard.nextLine();
      if(namesearch.equals("sentinelvalue"))//replace your sentinel value
          break;
```

If case not matter for sentinel value then can use

```
if(namesearch.equalsIgnoreCase("sentinelvalue"))//replace your sentinel value
              break;
```

Comment: leave a proper comment who ever downvoting, then i will edit the post accordingly